# what command will accomplish a successful push to a s3 bucket using maven-publish

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

[publishing maven repo to s3](https://vtorosyan.github.io/gradle-s3-private-repo/) assuming I have credentials and an existing bucket. What command do I call in order to run the publishing part of the build. With mavenDeployer I was using `gradle uploadArchives` but now I cant figure out how to get this binary to s3. Ive looked all over and nobody is showing the cli command to run it. Just the example setup in build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is doing this in 2 steps an option for you ?
step1 - maven/gradle will build the artifact / binary
step2 - use aws cli (s3) to upload - for e.g. `aws s3 cp /tmp/binary s3://bucket/`